# Clicking Submit changes the page on a Form even if there are validation errors

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am new to Sitecore 9 and still exploring Sitecore Experience Forms.

Should a forms go to the next page if there is a validation error on a field?

In WFFM it stayed on that page, but on my Experience Form, it is getting redirected to another page

Example: (The `dev_number` is a required field)
[image]

after clicking next it doesnt stay on the page
[image]

Can we make the form stay on the page out of the box Sitecore?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like validation is not working because of scripts are loaded properly from Layout. Forms gets redirected to formbuilder when it's missing the below script in MvcOuterLayout.cshtml

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html

@Html.RenderFormStyles()
@Html.RenderFormScripts()
```

Couple of more things to check:

1. Make sure you have two layouts - the outer layout that renders the script and the inner layout

> For form scripts and styles to be rendered, you must use two layouts:
>   MVC Layout.cshtml and MVC OuterLayout.cshtml. First, open the MVC
>   Layout.cshtml file and to refer to the outer layout that you will
>   create in the next step, add Layout = MVCOuterLayout.cshtml

Here is the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html)

2. Make sure to publish the forms, landing page and test the page in live mode(form validation doesn't work in preview mode).

Comment: Those 2 layouts available on premise when we are installing sitecore 9 or we have to create those 2 layouts?

Comment: @Vsn it needs to be created.